# jquery: how to hide second div?

Tags: jquery

i got a jquery question, how can I hide the first/second div, so now it shows Search, Search. I would like to have 'Search':

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Reload Grid" id="refresh_jqgProducts">
            <div class="ui-pg-div">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Search">
            <div class="ui-pg-div">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span>Search</div>
        </td>
        <td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" title="Search">
            <div class="ui-pg-div">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span>Search</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i tried something like: $("td .ui-pg-div :nth-child(1)") to retrieve this but to no avail.

Comment: Can't you just remove the td from the HTML? The last two seem identical?

Comment: Can't you just give it an ID?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot edit the HTML to remove this directly?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td .ui-pg-button').gt(0).find('div').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/gt
http://api.jquery.com/eq

Comment: don't you mean.eq(0)? He asked for the removal of a specific element ;-)

Comment: @Nebula actually my first answer **was** `eq(0)` but than I reread the question and now I really don't understand what the OP means.

Comment: @Roko ah, right. Turns out apparently that was what the OP meant based on his/her own answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found it with your help:

```
$("div.ui-pg-div:eq(1)").hide()
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-pg-button[title='Search']").gt(0).find('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, as you are working instantly in the element you will have to make sure you have Document.Ready in your scripts.

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('td[title="Search"]:first').remove();
}
```

I'm going to match any `td` with the title of 'Search' so that it will only ever hide the first occurence of the 'Search' item no matter the order.

I'm also removing the item, not just hiding it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:gt(1)').hide();​
```

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze2f5/)